# как сделать выборку по диапазону времени(timestamp)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Несколько дней изучаю postgresql.
Как сделать выборку всех данных по столбцу "date_", указав нужный веременно интервал от и до. Файл с данными [здесь](https://dropmefiles.com/Ya04t)
Таблицу сделал так:

```
quote=# CREATE TABLE stock (
quote(# date_ date_ timestamp PRIMARY KEY,
quote(# O double precision,
quote(# H double precision,
quote(# L double precision,
quote(# C double precision,
quote(# V double precision
quote(# );
```

данные таблицы:

```
    Таблица "public.stock"
 Столбец |             Тип             | Правило сортировки | Допустимость NULL | По умолчанию | Хранилище | Цель для статистики | Описание 
---------+-----------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+---------------------+----------
 date_   | timestamp without time zone |                    | not null          |              | plain     |                     | 
 o       | double precision            |                    |                   |              | plain     |                     | 
 h       | double precision            |                    |                   |              | plain     |                     | 
 l       | double precision            |                    |                   |              | plain     |                     | 
 c       | double precision            |                    |                   |              | plain     |                     | 
 v       | double precision            |                    |                   |              | plain     |                     | 
Индексы:
    "stock_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (date_)
Метод доступа: heap
```

сами данные выглядят так:

```
        date_        |    o    |    h    |    l    |    c    |   v    
---------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------
 2018-10-30 00:00:00 | 1.81198 | 1.81374 | 1.78596 | 1.78837 | 205467
 2018-10-31 00:00:00 | 1.78844 | 1.80817 | 1.78753 | 1.80407 | 196775
 2018-11-01 00:00:00 | 1.80402 | 1.80912 | 1.79434 | 1.80423 | 215630
 2018-11-02 00:00:00 | 1.80419 | 1.80566 |  1.7931 | 1.80143 | 216667
 2018-11-05 00:00:00 | 1.80994 | 1.81136 | 1.80168 | 1.80782 | 164551
 2018-11-06 00:00:00 | 1.80781 | 1.81472 | 1.79978 | 1.80699 | 196953
 2018-11-07 00:00:00 | 1.80698 | 1.81469 |  1.8003 | 1.80337 | 207837
```

Так же интересует, почему после создания таблицы и ее наполнения у меня не получилось установить в колонке "date_" PRIMARY KEY. Программа пишет, что есть NULL. Пришлось создавать новую таблицу. Можно ли установить PRIMARY KEY для уже существующей колонки.

Comment: Нашел ответ. SELECT * FROM stock WHERE DATE(date_) BETWEEN '2018-04-01' AND '2018-11-01';